# Объяснение тегов на примере сайта

Tags: оптимизация, seo

Всем привет! Сделал скриншот сайта, у которого вроде как все нормально с сео оптимизацией.

Можете, пожалуйста, рассказать какие теги тут изменяются от странице к странице, а какие статические (т.е. на каждой странице одинаковые).

Например, как тег с иконкой в браузере или название сайта, и что это за теги с `og` припиской в свойстве

[image: Скриншот случайного сайта]

Answer (score 1):

**Мета keywords**. Этот мета **[игнорируется Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812)**, а **[Бинг даже считает этот мета как сигнал спама](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2014/10/03/blame-the-meta-keyword-tag)**.

**Мета иконки**. Могут быть довольно полезны с использованием **[веб-манифеста](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)**. Статичны для всего веб-сайта.

Мета титлы и мета описание. Должны представлять субъект и главное содержание веб-страницы. Соответственно, должны иметь уникальное содержание для каждой веб-страницы. Для дополнительного изучения может быть полезно руководство **[Как создавать информативные заголовки и описания страниц для результатов поиска Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624)**.

То же самое относится к мета **og** - мета Фейсбук **[The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)**.